# Form data in view is lost or reset after modal popup

Tags: forms, view, yii2, modal-dialog

My form displays a dropdown list containing a list of statuses. When the selection changes a function is called thruough the dopdown list onchange property and the function calls up a modal. The intention is to gather additional user input thru an text input field.

After the modal is closed, however, the supposed changed status is no longer detected in my controller when the form is submitted. It seems the modal pop-up somehow lost the selected value in the form. Any help?

The dropdown list successfully triggers the function, thus the modal is shown. Nothing is done in the function for now, I just close it.

Here's how the form, modal, and function are placed in the view (among other things):

```
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id'=>'formSave',
        "class"=>"ph-form__inline", 'method' => 'post',
        'fieldConfig' => [
        'template' => "{input}",
        'options' => [
        'tag' => false,
        ],
        ],
    ]); 
    ?>  


<?= $form->field($model, 'status')->dropDownList($model->listAllowedStatuses($model->status),["prompt" =>'Select Status', "class" => "ph-form__inline", "id"=>"selStatus", "name"=>"selStatus", "onchange"=>"inputReason()"])->label(false)?>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="inputModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="input" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Please input (optional) reason for change:</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <?= $form->field($model, 'status_update_message')->input("text",["class" => "ph-form__input__field", "name"=>"textInput", "id"=>"textInput"])?> 
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="save()", id="save" name="save">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function inputReason(){
        $("#inputModal").modal('show');

    }
</script>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

The function that is triggered by drop-down's onchange, shows the modal: The plan is to add here the fetching of the text input data and placing it in the model, then close the modal, where a button is clicked in the underlying form to submit. The modal should not submit the form itself, just get input and "add" it to the  current form.

Perhaps this approach is wrong, or there's a better way to do it. Currently, it works in this setup: render form, select new value, click submit, and the controller detects the change and proceeds. After adding the modal, the controller no longer detects change:
render form, select new value, POP MODAL - accept text input - CLOSE, click submit, and the controller detects the change and proceeds. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Listen to modal close event and take the changes from there might work.

Comment: @InsaneSkull, thanks for the edits. Yes, I plan to retrieve the text inputted on the modal close event. Do you mean the form data will be "passed" to the modal so that I should check there? This will defeat the purpose of the save button on the underlying view/form

Comment: No, data inside modal retrieved and submitted along with form.